# Is there a way to pass a child container into the NserviceBus pipeline?

Tags: c#, wcf, autofac, nservicebus

Problem:
A request sent to a WCF service, which calls `IBus.SendLocal` creates two instances of an object configured as `InstancePerLifetimeScope()`

Background:
I'm using `Autofac.Integration.WCF` (which makes everything resolve 'per request', by providing a new child scope to each WCF request)

`IBus.SendLocal` invokes a message mutator, which gets injected with the same resource type as the wcf service

However, two different instances get created. One is injected into the service, a different instance is injected into the message mutator.

I'm assuming, this is because NSB creates its own child scope that's based on the root container.

Any ideas/pointers how to resolve this issue (ie have only a single instance created per WCF request)?

Edit: using NSB 4.3.2 and Autofac 3.5.2

Simplified configuration code

```
  Autofac.IContainer container = ConfigureIoc();

  Configure
    .With(AllAssemblies.Matching("this.dll").And("that.dll"))
    .DefineEndpointName("endpoint name here")
    .AutofacBuilder(container)
    .MsmqSubscriptionStorage()
    .UnicastBus()
    .CreateBus()
    .Start();

  ServiceHost host = CreateHost();
  host.AddDependencyInjectionBehavior(typeof(ISomeContract), container);
  host.Open();
```

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/particularsoftware/FiRKAsn938s

Comment: Just to be sure. Is this WCF service using the NServiceBus feature to expose an endpoint via WCF?

Comment: How did you initialize NServiceBus? Are you initializing NServiceBus by passing your container to it as mentioned here: http://docs.particular.net/samples/containers/autofac/

Comment: No to using the NSB feature, WCF service is self hosted.
Yes, the root container is passed into NSB (same one as the one used by the Autofac WCF integration)

Comment: I've a "simple" sample that shows the issue. I'll post it on GitHub tomorrow. The issue is still there when using NSB 5.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modified `NServiceBus.Autofac` [object builder](https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus.Autofac/blob/develop/src/NServiceBus.Autofac/AutofacObjectBuilder.cs) to enable child scope resolution through a factory.

The `ILifetimeScope` factory returns an [`AutofacInstanceContext.Current.OperationLifetime`](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac.Wcf/blob/master/src/Autofac.Integration.Wcf/AutofacInstanceContext.cs#L91) which is the child container used by WCF.

https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus.Autofac/pull/2

Answer (score 2):

A child container is created when a message is received by NServiceBus. In your scenario a call/message is not received by NServiceBus but by WCF. All calls that you make then will use the root container that is created when NServiceBus is initialized.

#### Registration via Autofac

```
builder.RegisterType<MyMutator>().AsImplementedInterfaces().AsSelf().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

#### Registration via NServiceBus

```
busConfiguration.RegisterComponents(x => x.ConfigureComponent<MyMutator>(DependencyLifecycle.InstancePerUnitOfWork));
```

It is currently (v5) not possible to have a child container created when calling `Bus.SendLocal` while not in the context of receiving a message on a NService endpoint.

A solution would be to convert the WCF call into *one* message and do a send local. This message is then processed an NServiceBus message handler which can then do sending/publishing of multiple message and have the mutator behavior that you require (single instance per unit of work).

I have build a sample project using WCF and NServiceBus that demonstrates the unit of work lifetime scope behavior:

https://github.com/ramonsmits/wcfnsbtest

Comment: thanks for your reply @Ramon. I still have to get this fixed and have extended `NServiceBus.Autofac` to support injecting a factory of `ILifetimeScope`.